# ThreeJS Curving Stream Animation

Tags: path, three.js, curve

I'm new to this so pardon me if I'm not quite giving enough detail about something, but... I'm trying to make a sort of curving stream, like water coming out of a fountain, only with more distinct particles than a continuous stream. I admit, I have no idea where to start as the documentation on threejs.org seems incomplete. Basically I want to have particles shoot out of one point and curve down into another. I figure I can use CurvePath or some such thing, as (as far as I know) I can specify a curve with a ridiculous number of points (is there a way to do a curve perhaps by specifying start and end points, rotation, and distance from the center to the apex?) and then I assume there's a straightforwardish way to make something move along a Path.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a limited amount of objects to want to move along a path, the way I would do it is

- as you said, create a Curve (look at the [Curve subclasses](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Core/Curve) to find one that suits you)
- use something like [Tween.js](https://github.com/sole/tween.js/) or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/animate) to execute an [easing](http://easings.net) function from 0 to 1
- pass the easing value to `Curve.getPoint(distance)` to get a position along the path
- add some randomness on this point to make a stream effect

Or, using a kind-of-physical particle engine, like http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Particle-Engine.html